# For security reason and processing speed in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to ensure security is on-point while I assure that the processing speed of a web site is not frustrating as well.

Is it best from a security perspective to do most of the coding on the client-side or on the server-side (C#)?

Here is an example:

Client-side

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm"
PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx" />
```

and
Server-side

```
btnConfirm.PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx"
```

Which one seems to be secure and at the same time load the page faster?

Comment: This question is too broad and the only real answer to it is that neither client nor server side code is inherently more secure than the other. Security and performance both require knowing what you're doing and writing code that accomplishes the given task efficiently and securely.  Entire series of books are written on each topic.

Comment: The 2 code snippets seem to be totally equivalent. It's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes @bomelding, they are the same. Only some are on the client-side and others on the server-side

Comment: They both run server side in '~Confirm.aspx"

Comment: You think something with `runat="server"` in it is running client side?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got some background assumptions wrong here. The difference between your two code snippets is *not* client vs. server-side, but rather that one is done in C# code, while the other is done in the markup (xml).

That does not mean that one will run server-side, and the other on the client; both are processed before anything is sent to the client, and the result of these two should be equivalent.

You can verity this yourself by looking at the resulting HTML in your browser; it will not contain anything like `<asp:button ...>` - that is an **asp.net** specific element, which is interpreted / processed (?) into regular HTML before it is sent to the client (your web browser).

**Short answer: Your assumptions are wrong: Both run on the server side, and should be equivalent.**